# Python Pandas Filter Zero cell

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am trying to filter a dataframe by all none zero's. My df is:

```
    Name    Fruit   Total
0   Steve   Orange  0
1   Bob     Apple   15
2   Cindy   Grapes  27
3   Grant   Orange  37
```

I want to remove Steve from the data DF. New to Pandas here but I have tried this and it doesn't seem to work. I have tried looking at the documents for loc but I think I am missing something here on how to use loc.

```
df.loc[(df!=0).any(axis=1)]
```

This is just a sample. I want to remove all Total's that are zero.

Comment: If you are filtering just based on column `Total`, you can do: `df[df.Total != 0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df[~(df==0).any(axis=1)])
    Name   Fruit  Total
1    Bob   Apple     15
2  Cindy  Grapes     27
3  Grant  Orange     37
```

But if only numeric is column `Total` use:

```
df[df.Total != 0]
```

**Explanation**:

If in `DataFrame` is more numeric columns - so you can get `0` not only in last column, but also in anothers, use:

First compare all values with `0` - get `boolean DataFrame`:

```
print (df==0)
    Name  Fruit  Total
0  False  False   True
1  False  False  False
2  False  False  False
3  False  False  False
```

If need find at least one `True` (`0`) per columns need [`any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) with `axis=0`:

```
print ((df==0).any(axis=0))
Name     False
Fruit    False
Total     True
dtype: bool
```

But if need at least one `True` (`0`) per rows add `axis=1`:

```
print ((df==0).any(axis=1))
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
dtype: bool
```

Invert `boolean Series` by `~`:

```
print (~(df==0).any(axis=1))
0    False
1     True
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

and use `boolean indexing`:

```
print (df[~(df==0).any(axis=1)])
    Name   Fruit  Total
1    Bob   Apple     15
2  Cindy  Grapes     27
3  Grant  Orange     37
```

Comment: That worked Thanks. Do you mind if I ask what the ~ is doing and why do I set the axis to 1